# Raiserror level 16 that does not abort the procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, procedure, raiserror

Hi all I have a stored procedure that has checks to see if a batch_id exists in a table named valid. If exists I want to abort the remainder of the procedure. I have

```
If exists(select batch_id 
          from valid
          Where batch_id=@bid)
Raiserror ('file has been extracted already',16,1)
```

But it does not abort the rest of the procedure

Comment: Could you post the procedure body?

Comment: SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER proc [Lamb].[ETL]
as


SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET ANSI_PADDING ON;

bulk insert Lamb.temp1 from 'c:\temp\Locality_Extract_01.csv' with (fieldterminator = ',');

insert into Lamb.temp (PostCode, Suburb, State) select * from Lamb.temp1
order by state;


if exists(select Batch_id from lamb.Invalid_locality
where Batch_id=1)
raiserror('file has already been extracted',16,1)

Answer (score 0):

`raiserror` doesn't abort the batch, cf. [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx).  You might have gotten that impression because some *clients* may cancel the query for errors above some severity threshold.

To exit the procedure on error, raise the error and return a negative status. I usually `return -50000 - @@error` to make sure I'm in the designated range.

Comment: You could also try using the `THROW` command instead of `RAISERROR`. I believe this alwyas terminates a batch, unless it is used inside of a `TRY` block.